# Only allow exact type (not subclasses) in C++

Tags: c++, types, subclass, invariance

Is is possible to declare types where it only allows that class and not any subclasses (I know this violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) but I still want to know if there's a way to do it.)
For example,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};

void fn(/*I want this to be only A, not subclasses*/A arg) {
    // do stuff with arg
    std::cout << "fn called";
}

int main() {
    A a;
    fn(a);
    B b;
    fn(b);  // should raise compile-time error here
}
```

I want `fn(b)` to give a compile-time error.

Link to code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/AiLkHwp5rg7AD7gf

Comment: Why? `arg` is already always `A` because of object slicing. Why does it matter to you if that `A` was produced as a copy of a `B` or another `A`?

Comment: `void fn(A arg)` the arg can **only** be an `A`, it **cannot** be a subclass.  On the other hand, `void fn(A const& arg)` the arg can be `A` or anything derived from `A`.

Comment: Is your need to pass the object by value or can it be by reference?

Comment: LSP doesn't even come into play here because there is no polynorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to approach this, so let's compare them:

### Constraints (since C++20)

```cpp
#include <concepts>

// abbreviated function template, could also write:
//   template <std::same_as<A> T>
void fn(std::same_as<A> auto arg)  {
    std::cout << "fn called";
}
```

###### Diagnostic

```
<source>:8:6: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with arg:auto = B]
void fn(std::same_as<A> auto arg)  {
     ^
<source>:8:9: note: because 'std::same_as<B, A>' evaluated to false
void fn(std::same_as<A> auto arg)  {
        ^
```

This option works because `auto` is deduced to `B` here, which is not the same as `A`. The constraint doesn't care that `B` is convertible to `A` (although `std::convertible_to` would).

###### Pros and Cons

- short and simple
- errors are slightly verbose by comparison
- requires fairly recent version of C++
- intent conveyed clearly in code

### `std::enable_if` and SFINAE (since C++11)

```cpp
// note: convenience aliases is_same_v and enable_if_t are not available in C++11 yet
//       this solution is C++17
template <typename T>
auto fn(T arg) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, A>> {
    std::cout << "fn called";
}
```

###### Diagnostic

```
<source>:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same_v<B, A>'
                    was not satisfied [with T = B]
auto fn(T arg) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, A>> {
     ^
```

This implementation is basically the same as the C++20 version, we just do it via SFINAE instead of constraints.

###### Pros and Cons

- more verbose than C++20 counterpart, but bearable

  - solution is much uglier in C++11 because there are no convenience aliases
- only clang has diagnostics *this good* for `std::enable_if`, other compilers will produce much worse output
- intent conveyed clearly like in the former solution

### Deleted functions (since C++11)

```cpp
void fn(A arg) {
    std::cout << "fn called";
}

template <typename T>
void fn(T arg) = delete;
```

###### Diagnostic

```
<source>:14:6: note: candidate function [with T = B] has been explicitly deleted
void fn(T arg) = delete;
     ^
<source>:8:6: note: candidate function
void fn(A arg) {
     ^
```

We are allowed to declare any function as deleted, where calling it makes the program ill-formed.
This solution works because `fn(T)` wins in overload resolution, as no implicit conversion from `B` to `T` is required, only from `B` to `A`.

###### Pros and Cons

- requires function overloading
- `= delete` on arbitrary functions is surprising, it's not a well-known feature
- intent not conveyed as clearly in code, we must look at the overload set as a whole to understand it
- no standard library dependency, i.e. good for compile speed potentially and very portable

### `static_assert` (since C++11)

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fn(T arg) {
    // or std::is_same_v in C++17
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, A>::value, "fn must be called with A");
    std::cout << "fn called";
}
```

###### Diagnostic

```
<source>:10:5: error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'std::is_same<B, A>::value':
                      fn must be called with A
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, A>::value, "fn must be called with A");
    ^
```

This is a very simple, but effective solution.
We check whether the type we were given is actually `A`. No implicit conversions from `B` to `A` would be considered.

###### Pros and Cons

- no error at the call site (bad IDE support, usually no red underline shown)
- very clear diagnostic, customizable by us so we can convey intent

### Conclusion

The quality of errors is alright for every solution, at least when using clang.
Which solution you prefer depends in part on what requirements you have, and what version of C++ you want to be compatible with.
However, personal preference also plays a role here, since none of the solutions are better than others in *every* regard.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) concept:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

void fn(std::same_as<A> auto arg)  {
    std::cout << "fn called";
}
```

Comment: But same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76588444/1312382): Cannot prevent a user from casting…

Comment: @Aconcagua If the user of the function slices the object into an `A`, then an `A` is actually what is provided to the function.

Comment: Sure, but that was already the case in original variant as well, just not requiring an explicit cast…

Comment: @Aconcagua I thought that was the whole point. If the caller has made sure to have an `A` and not something derived from an `A` or implicitly convertible to `A`, the function should accept it, otherwise reject.

Comment: You mean preventing *accidental* object slicing? Interesting point, but there are just too many other places where that might occur so really not sure how much value countermeasures at one single spot actually have. I personally would not consider it worth the efforts ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua I mean both slicing and conversions. OP is aware enough (_"I know this violates..."_) to know that this isn't probably the proper place to implement this check. The _"I still want to know if there's a way to do it"_ part is about satisfying curiosity as I understood it.

Answer (score 6):

You can delete functions

```
template<typename T>
void fn(T arg)=delete;
```

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};

void fn(A arg) {
    // do stuff with arg
    std::cout << "fn called";
}

template<typename T>
void fn(T arg)=delete;

int main() {
    A a;
    fn(a);
    B b;
    fn(b);  // should raise compile-time error here
}
```

Because the template matches everything, it is always considered in the overload resolution. Since non-templates are preferred to templates, `fn(A{});` is a better candidate than the template, on the other hand `fn(B{});` matches the template exactly while the non-template would require an implicit cast.

Of course, you cannot forbid someone casting `B` to `A` before the calls so the solution is brittle and confusing at best.

Answer (score 4):

You might forbid other overload:

```
void fn(A arg) {
    // do stuff with arg
    std::cout << "fn called";
}

template <typename T> void fn(T) = delete;
```